# How to find service name in webmethods which are used in a transformer

Tags: webmethods

Am trying to print the names of services invoked in a FlowService using  a java program. Am able to print the names of services using below code:

```
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.InvokeState;
...
...
...

InvokeState invkState = InvokeState.getCurrentState();
//below line prints all service names which are invoked in a flow service
System.out.println(invkState.getCallStack());
```

However, when am using transformers and trying to invoke a custom service (which I created), the above code doesn't print the services which are invoked via transformer. And if, I happened to use a pub service, then it displays service name but not in the case of custom service.

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2of9.png) for better understanding.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you wish obtain exactly? System.out.println cannot give an output to your pipeline, you need to map to pipeline output either by PipelineCursor or IDataMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried mapping my transformers output to the pipeline, my code started displaying service names which was invoked using transformer.

Figured out that transformers are only invoked when they have mapped outputs to the outgoing pipeline of the step.